# Proving that permutations $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are of the same type

Tags: combinatorics

Proving that permutations $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are of the same type.

Can someone give me like a hint to start proving this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reversing every cycle of $p$ would result in $p^{-1}$, thus they're the same type.

Comment: +1, but: When the question mentions $f$, why use $p$?

Answer (score 2):

We can also see this problem from different point of view that is Group Theory. I f we establish $\Omega=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ then $S_{\Omega}=\{f:\Omega\to\Omega, f~\text{is bijective}\}$. It is well-known that we denote the elements of $S_n$ as permutations on $n$ alphabets. Now, if we select an element $\pi\in S_n$ of length $r$: $$\pi=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_r)$$ then clearly while $\pi(\alpha_i)=\alpha_j,~~1\le i,j\le r$ we have $\pi^{-1}(\alpha_j)=\alpha_i$. So, if we accept that we can write $\pi$ as follows:
$$\pi=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)(\alpha_1,\alpha_3)\cdots(\alpha_1,\alpha_r)$$ then $\pi^{-1}$ also have the same cycle type.

Comment: $\quad \oplus_+^+\langle + \rangle \quad$